# Nifi: how to combile 14 000 flowfile in one file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I  have  1400  flowFile  with  same  name and  i  want to  enroll them  into  one   file, i  have  read  that  i can use  mergeContent  processor  for  this  purpose  but  when  the  amount  of  flowfile  is  more  than  10000 it  can't combine them in one   file,  what  should  i  change  to  make  this  processor  work   properly?  here  is  my  configuration image  example:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

i think 10000 is a limit of the incoming queue.

just extend your incoming queue to fit more then 10000 files.